# How to convert string to date in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a csv file where a column has date information in the following format- `07-17-2020`. I want to read the file and sort the contents by date and then group by year. How can I do this in Jekyll Liquid?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<table>
{% assign citations_grouped_by_year = site.data.citations | sort: 'Year' | reverse | group_by: 'Year' %}
{% for year in citations_grouped_by_year %}
  <tr>
  <td><h3>{{year.name}}</h3></td>
  </tr>
  {% for citation in year.items %}
  <tr>
<td>
{{citation.Authors}}. {{citation.Title | camelize}}. <i>{{citation.Publication}}</i>. {{citation.Year}}
</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```